# Save all changes in DataList on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, datalist

I have the following DataList-

```
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Exclude"></asp:Label>
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="excludeTextBox">
<ItemTemplate>

<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Active"></asp:Label>
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="activeCheck" >

<ItemTemplate>

<br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  Checked='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Equals("1") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

</td>
```

So this is generating a textBox and checkBox for every row that exits in the database.

Currently there is no save action associated with the dataList, however if a user checks or unchecks one of the checkBoxes this calls a webservice and toggles the value in a data base table.

My question is, after a user has edited the text in some of the textBoxes and checked or unchecked some of the check boxes, how can I catch the changes in a `save changes` button. Because if the items have been dynamically created then technically they do not exist on the page. I want to do this without having a save option on ever row on the dataList.

```
protected void saveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // capture all edits and call update webservice method.   
}
```

Comment: have you tried a `google search` it appears you have not tried anything on your own in regards to `codebehind` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976245/add-string-item-to-datalist-asp-net here is a place to start reading

Comment: _"Because if the items have been dynamically created then technically they do not exist on the page"_ That's wrong. Every control in an `Template` of a webdatabound-control like `DataList` is created and recreated on every postback. It does exist in the page. You can access it via `DataListItem.FindControl(Id)`.

Comment: Are you saying the checkbox already updates a value in the database when being (un)checking?

Answer (score 1):

You'd essentially have to build the representation of the changes.  Because there is no generic solution to this, I don't have any code, but here is the process:

As an item changes, you have to store what changed.  You could store the indexes of the rows that actually changed in a hidden variable on the page, or store the changes in a JavaScript object.  When save changes is clicked, on the client you then loop through these changes, and if they exist send them in bulk or one at a time.

If you had a hidden field with a value like `0,2,5` for each index that changed, you could easily find those items, grab the values from the form, and ship them off to the web service.  Or, you could build a JavaScript object that has the changes like:

```
{ key: 2, checked: true, text:"My new text" }
```

Store these in an array, and push them up to the server through the web service.

Comment: I think I understand how your solution would work. So if I mark when a row has been altered, then in the save button click, for each row that has been changed, call the web service update method with the new user input?

Comment: Right I shall try and implement this code and make sure I mark this as correct if it works, thanks for the constructive answer.